Tracking progress for long running jobs with OTEL
I am looking for a good approach to adding observability to some long running jobs in our application.
The application is dotnet 8.
Our application will sometimes start a background task to execute some integration work, and these tasks might take several hours.
I've installed the Azure.Monitor.OpenTelemetry.AspNetCore nuget package in the project.
The objective is this

Ability to see in insights that a job has started, before it has finished
Ability to see progress information during the run: "started step X" etc.
Ensure that the information from these jobs are not sampled out
Ensure that normal web request traffic follows a configured sampling rate
Ensure that non-integration-job log entries are only sent above level "warning"

Challenges
I can't use a single span/activity around the whole job, as far as I can tell, because then nothing will get sent until it has completed.
I can use the ILogger within a span/activity, but then it will be subject to global log levels.
If I use "span events", then they will not get transmitted until the span completes.
It does not seem possible to customize sample rates for the Application Insights exporter

Your conclusions so far are correct, and this isn't a very solved problem right now I'm afraid across most observability backends.
Ultimately the answer right now is "multiple spans".
Treat it like messaging.

Generate a span for sending the action to the background (it might be the action of sending it to a database, or putting it on a background channel) and end it.
Generate a span when you pick it up from the DB/channel for one part of the processing and end it.
Generate spans for the next action and end it.

You will end up with a distributed trace where there isn't a single span that covers the whole action.
If you need to query the start/end, you can either do some funky querying (platform dependent, but for kusto/Azure monitor you can do it which seems to be what you're doing) or you can propagate the start time down the chain using baggage and add it to the last span.
There are observability backends that do make that sort of querying easier, remember not all backends are the same, some are more geared towards these kinds of workflows than others, so it this is your sole usecase, maybe consider other options.

Hi, it has been a while since this answer, is this still true? I have a long running task and want to be able to report that it is running late - while it hapens.
